Is a period used after a ligature of an abbreviation if its constituent characters, separated, would be punctuated in that manner?
That question title is fairly nondescript, but it has to be to encompass the undermentioned example. Specifically, consider how № (Numero) replaces "No." In this situation, should I place a full-stop after №, like "№.", or should I solely ever use it as merely the former?
The reason I ask is because Numero is visually (and, in the case of ligatures, literally) a combination of "N" and "o", solely stylistically modified. Consequently, I expect that it would be punctuated as its constituent letters would be if separated.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_indicator

Wikipedia (rather than a dictionary) is an obvious source; the article 'Numero sign' lists № / Nº /  No̱ /  No. / no. as representations. Note which have periods. // M-W even licences no (no period) as a variant (I'd say this was more a UK usage).

I'm not sure why you consider 'no' to be a truncation. 'Mon', 'Oct' are examples of truncation, while 'no' is a contraction. // In line with many Brits, I suppress traditional full stops unless to do so would cause lack of clarity. This can become awkward in an analysis of available abbreviated variants.

@EdwinAshworth, truncations are surely a form of contraction (although, obviously, truncation is more specific)? Irrespective, “No.” appears to be a truncation because it is “Number” truncated to its first two letters, and then misspelled (because it was originally colloquial).

What are you using the symbol in? I wouldn't expect it to be in the body of text. If it's in a title, there is more latitude to do what looks nice, and if it's in a logo, poster, card, etc, the freedom is greater still.

No, it is N[umer]o, see Why is the word 'number' abbreviated to 'no' in UK English and in American....  For truncation vs contraction, see, for instance, linguistic convencions/abreviacions (although 'BrE' is a pipedream, and few abbreviations are afforded a full stop by many in the UK).

@Stuart, I'm using it as the label of an HTML <th> — a table header. It heads the left-most table column of list entries (<li>s), like this image depicts.

@EdwinAshworth, what do you refer to as "BrE"? (Do you consider UK-style delimitation of an abbreviation with a period to be erroneous?)

" 'BrE' is a pipedream" seems an adequate statement. 'That which is considered acceptable in Britain' suggests itself, but a study by Quirk and Svartvik showed that 'acceptability' is ill-defined, with different accomplished Anglophones disagreeing on some usages. In France, the language is controlled by an established authority, but it doesn't stop natives using 'forbidden' forms. // The dictionaries I mention license No. and no. and no as acceptable variants. The interchange of US and UK personnel makes saying one of these is incorrect in area A implausible. And what about mid-Atlantic?

@EdwinAshworth, I don't know what you're talking about. The phrase “an adequate statement” is fairly meaningless, especially without context. I just want to know what "BrE" means. Thanks for the verbosity, though.

'BrE' is short for 'British English', which according to Wikipedia is 'the set of varieties of the English language native to the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland'. The snag is that the set of varieties contains differing and at times conflicting  usages (and as stated, there is not even agreement among accomplished English language graduates (the Svartvik/Quirk study above) about exactly what is acceptable). Also, some English people might prefer 'US spellings' or 'US grammar conventions'. 'BrE' is not well-defined.

@EdwinAshworth, thanks. You're definitely correct - standard-form English here is frequently standardised to whatever the Oxford Dictionary states, because the myriad regional dialects.

... 'Here' being? And which Oxford dictionary? ODE (which is freely available, and misnamed by some 'Google Dictionary') and OED are distinct works, not always in total agreement.

"Here" being the country of England (UN/LOCODE ENG), and whichever IANA considers the language code "en-GB-oxendict" to refer to, per en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Oxford_spelling&oldid=1258687172#cite_note-4.

I couldn't find any meaningful citations.  However, the correct abbreviation for number is No. and it is widely used that way.
If you wanted to use № then the period after it looks strange, so I would not use the period.  Wiktionary certainly does not use one.  Neither does Abbreviations.

This figure is only used before a numeral.

Although I'm genuinely thankful, if “looks strange” was enough to decide with, I wouldn't have needed to ask. Thanks for the citations. Additionally, I'm solely asking about the numero symbol in this context, since “No.” isn't a symbol — it's a series thereof.

It’s not our job to infer the logical processes of questioners. But if you use it, the period belongs in line with the o, as it is not an end-of-sentence period.

<< A correct abbreviation for number is No. >> is correct.

"No." does not indicate a truncation.
I cannot think of a context in which "No." would end a sentence.
There "co." as a truncation of company:

John said "The best onions are sold by Smith and Co."

It would be incorrect to write

John said "The best onions are sold by Smith and Co.."

John said "The best onions are sold by Smith and Co".


but a matter of style to write 1. above or

John said "The best onions are sold by Smith and Co.".


I agree that double punctuation is not incorrect per se. //// Many, especially in the UK, drop the full stop once so prevalent in all types of abbreviations. Collins lists variants it considers acceptable.

Greybeard, your 2nd statement appears to lack context. Specifically, have I accidentally asked whether, or purported that, “No.” might end a sentence? Likewise, whether to write a period after an abbreviation is a different question — this one solely asks about whether ligatures of abbreviations should be punctuated as if they were separate characters.

Thanks for mentioning that it's not a truncation. I've rephrased it to say “abbreviation” instead.

@RokeJulianLockhart Specifically, have I accidentally asked whether, or purported that, “No.” might end a sentence? Yes, you seem to have done. If № has no attached stop and "No." does, why. otherwise, would you ask?

@Greybeard, because periods are frequently utilized to delimit abbreviations. They're not solely utilized to end sentences. If you're unaware of that, I presume that whatever dialect of English you utilize does not incorporate that? English English does, for reference.

Your presumptions are rather limited. Try to find less challenging work.
